# Read second word of a file in c

Tags: c, arrays, file, vector

I have this function in c that saves in a integer variable all the numbers from a file. But I want to make a change so I can save just the second numbers between spaces of each line into a vector and then print all the vector. Here is the example of file.txt:

```
123  19
321  18
432  9
876  16
875  17
```

And here is the code that must be changed:

```
void LerVetor(int *V, int *N) {
        FILE *fp;
        int marks;
        fp = fopen("dados3.txt", "r");

        if(fp == NULL)
                printf("Falha ao abrir ficheiro\n");


        rewind(fp);

        do {
                fscanf(fp, "%d", &marks);
                printf("%d\n", marks);

        }
        while(!feof(fp));


        fclose(fp);

}
```

The output is the same as the file.txt because the code is just print me the content of the file.

Resume: Save just the second numbers of each line, ex: 19, 18, 9..., in a vector and then print the vector.

Comment: You can read the input line by line using `fgets`. Than depending on the exact specification of the input format there are different ways to get the second number in every line. One option is to use `strtol`(with the necessary error handling) two times.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file line-by-line using `fgets` and extract the desired part of each line using `sscanf`. If you do not know the length of the vector (= number of lines) before reading, you can dynamically increase the vector with each read line using `realloc`:

```
char line[20];
int *vector = NULL;
int length = 0;

// open file
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
    vector = realloc(vector, (length+1)*sizeof(int));
    sscanf(line, "%*d %d\n", &vector[length++]);
}
// close file
```

Then you can print the resulting vector like this:

```
printf("Read %d numbers:\n", length); 
for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
    printf("%d\n", vector[i]);
```

And of course do not forget to `free` the allocated memory.